# LINQ subquery in azure function app returns error message

Tags: c#, linq, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an azure function for getting Mappings from a azure cosmos db document. However, it fails when trying to run a query within a query.

```
        private static string GetKey(IEnumerable<Server> servers, int serverId)
            => servers.Where(s => s.ServerId == serverId).ToList().First().Key;
        

        public static IEnumerable<Mapping> GetMappings(DocumentClient documentClient)
            => GetSitesDocumentQuery(documentClient)
                .SelectMany(site => site.Terminals
                    .Select(terminal => new Mapping
                    {
                        Key = GetKey(site.Servers, terminal.ServerId),
                        // [...]
                    })
                )
                .ToList();
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
 ProcessMessage. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. 
 (Method 'GetKey' is not supported., Windows/10.0.19042 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.12.0). 
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Method 'GetKey' is not supported., Windows/10.0.19042 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.12.0.
```

They're both members of the same class.

If I inline the query

```
        public static IEnumerable<Mapping> GetMappings(DocumentClient documentClient)
            => GetSitesDocumentQuery(documentClient)
                .SelectMany(site => site.Terminals
                    .Select(terminal => new Mapping
                    {
                        Key = site.Servers.Where(s => s.ServerId == serverId).AsEnumerable().First().Key,
                        // [...]
                    })
                )
                .ToList();
```

I get the same error message except now it claims `First()` is not supported.

Comment: I had a similar issue caused by having different projects referencing different versions of the Cosmos SDK. Make sure all package references are targeting the same version of the Cosmos SDK.

Comment: `site.Servers` - likely an `IQueryable<T>` - doesn't support translating that custom logic into the query. On your second attempt, it seems like the `AsEnumerable()` is throwing it off. I would expect `Key = site.Servers.First(s => s.ServerId == serverId).Key` to work. If not, you could also do `Key = site.Servers.Where(s => s.ServerId == serverId).ToArray().First().Key`.

Comment: @RichMercer thanks for the suggestion, but I have not been able to find any such conflict

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError `site.Servers` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`. I have tried both your suggestions , but none of them worked sadly (Method 'First' not supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you do .AsEnumerable() or .ToList() before the .SelectMany(..)?

Comment: Thank you ever so much; this did the trick